# Error with \^ in c# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that contains colours in the form of "^##" where ## can be 00-99.

I wrote regex to detect and replace these colours:

`Input = Regex.Replace(Input, "\^[0-9][0-9]", "");`

However the compiler doesn't seem to like \^ as a means of detecting the "^" character (gives an invalid escape code error). So how do I go about looking for the ^ character in c# regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because, well, there's no such escape sequence (`\^`)

You can use:

- C# verbatim strings: `@"\^[0-9][0-9]"`
- Two backslashes instead of one: `"\\^[0-9][0-9]"`

Tips:

- The character class `[0-9]` is equivalent to the shorthand `\d`
- Instead of having `[0-9][0-9]` you could use `[0-9]{2}` (or `\d{2}`). This helps when you have more repetitions.

#### References:

[Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips, it's now at @"\^\d{2}", slightly less readable but I'll add a little comment in there. :D

Comment: @Blam Well, that depends on how familiar with regex the person reading is ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using verbatim string in Regex

```
Input = Regex.Replace(Input, @"\^[0-9][0-9]", "");
```

If you want to learn more about string literals read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: thanks works perfectly (baww can't set as accepted answer yet).

Answer (score 0):

Try a double-slash `"\\^"`

The slash is a control character in creating the string object itself.

But you want the string to contain a slash itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since the C# compiler itself gives special meaning to a `\` in a string, if you want a string to contain a `\` you must do one of two things:

- escape it by doubling it: `\\`
- make the string a verbatim string, by preceding the opening `"` with a `@` : `@"\"` - but note that this latter option changes how quotes (`"`) in the string must be escaped